# Android: line numbering

Tags: android

I'm actually trying to display the line numbering at the left of an `EditText` as shown in the figure.

[image]

The problem is that whenever a new line is added or removed to the file, it take a while to recalculate the string containing the line numbering.

What I do is the following: whenvere there is a type, I check whether the line count of the `EditText` has changed, if it is the case I just append the missing line at the end of the `TextView` showing the line numbering.

So if we take the piece of code in the image and press the new line key, my code get the line count (14 since we added a line) and append `14 + System.lineSeparator()` to the `TextView` by using `linesTextView.append(newText)`.

As said the application is lagging. Is there a way to efficently modify the content of a `TextView`?

Another solution that came in my mind was to use a `TextView` for each line number and just remove or add a new `TextView` when the line count of the content has changed. The problem about that is that I cannot make the `TextViews` be aligned with the lines of the `EditText`.

Thank you

EDIT:
Forgot to add the code

```
public class CodeEditView extends LinearLayout implements TouchEditText.TouchEditTextListener{

    private View root;
    private InternalFile file;
    private TouchEditText code;
    private ScrollView scroll;
    private int linesCount;
    private TextView lines;
    private int currentStartLine;
    private int currentEndLine;


    public CodeEditView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, context);
    }

    public CodeEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, context);
    }


    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, Context context) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        root = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_code_layout, this).findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

        this.lines = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_code_lines_view);
        this.code = (TouchEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_code_content_view);
        code.setRoot(root);
        code.setListener(this);
        linesCount = 0;
        scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
//                int scrollY = scroll.getScrollY();
//                if(scrollY != 0) {
//                    code.scrollEvent();
//                    if(currentStartLine < code.getCurrentStartLine()) {
//
//                        String c = lines.getText().toString();
//                        String cc = c.replaceFirst("\\d+", " ");
//                        cc += Integer.toString(code.getCurrentEndLine()+10) + System.lineSeparator();
//                        lines.setText(cc);
//                        currentStartLine = code.getCurrentStartLine();
//
//                    } else {
////                        CharSequence c = lines.getText();
////                        lines.setText(lines.getText().);
//                    }
//                }
                int scrollY = scroll.getScrollY();
                if(scrollY != 0) {
                    code.scrollEvent();
                }


            }
        });

    }

    public void setFile(InternalFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void setLexer(Lexer lexer) {
        code.setLexer(lexer);
    }

    private void initLines() {
//        currentStartLine = code.getCurrentStartLine();
//        currentEndLine = code.getCurrentEndLine();
//        int usedLines = code.getLineCount();
//        if(usedLines != linesCount) {
//
//            String text = "";
//
//            for(int i = currentStartLine; i <= currentEndLine+10; i++) {
//                text += Integer.toString(i) + System.lineSeparator();
//            }
//            lines.setText(text);
//            linesCount = usedLines;
//        }
        int usedLines = code.getLineCount();
        String text = "";
        for(int i = 1; i <= usedLines; i++) {
            text += Integer.toString(i) + System.lineSeparator();
        }
        Log.d("TEXT", Integer.toString(usedLines));
        lines.setText(text);
        linesCount = usedLines;




    }

    public void initText(String content) {
        code.initText(content);

        code.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initLines();
            }
        });

    }


    public void setFont(Typeface typeFace) {
        this.lines.setTypeface(typeFace);
        this.code.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTyped(String text) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateCacheFileEvent(text,file));
        setLines();
    }

    public void forceSyntax(Syntax s) {
        code.forceSyntax(s);
    }

    private void setLines() {
        int usedLines = code.getLineCount();
        if(usedLines > linesCount) {

            lines.append(Integer.toString(usedLines) + System.lineSeparator());
            linesCount = usedLines;
        } else {
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Actually the line numbers are in a separated `TextView`

Comment: apparently you are recreating the number of lines at each character typed?

Comment: No, `setLines` is called only if the line count has changed. An I dont recreate all the numbers, but I just append the number of the new line at the end

Comment: did you try to identify which part is actually slowing your app down?

Comment: Im not sure but probably is the `setLine` method. In particular, the `append`.